# Having to restart Android Studio everytime I add a new dependency in pubspec.yaml| Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dependencies

Whenever I add a new dependency/package in pub spec and run my code is throws out the error:

Compiler message:
Error: Could not resolve the package 'circulardropdownmenu'

It works after I restart android studio.

Comment: Instead of restarting android studio. Rerun the app again from the start....

Comment: Did you remember to run 'Pub get?' (If not, it should be up in the right corner as a little blue link thing, just click it and it should help, at least if you forgot before)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to re-run (build) the app, and then wait a minute or so.

The `pub get` link that Android Studio offers in the `pubspec.yaml` file is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

in your terminal try:

```
flutter pub get
```